# Cut order all fields except one

Tags: linux, bash, cut

I'm having problems with the order cut, i'm trying to show all the fields from a document except the second one without knowing the total number of fields how. I already tried this:

```
cut -f -2- example
```

I don't seem to find the correct option for doing it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
cut -f1,3- file
```

This will print field 1 and all fields from 3 onwards.

Note that default delimiter for `cut` is a tab character.

Answer (score 5):

use `cut -f2 --complement example`

It prints all the fields but the 2nd one.

> ```
>   --complement        complement the set of selected bytes, characters
>                         or fields.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/cut/

7. Select All Fields Except the Specified Fields

> In order to complement the selection field list use option --complement.

```
cut --complement -f2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cut --complement -f2 -d " " fich.txt
```

Test with file fich.txt :

```
A1 B1 C1 D1
A2 B2 C2 D2
A3 B3 C3 D3

cut --complement -f2 -d " " fich.txt
A1 C1 D1
A2 C2 D2
A3 C3 D3
```

Explications

```
   -d, --delimiter=DELIM
     use DELIM instead of TAB for field delimiter
```